# How to extract JSON array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, nsarray

How to extract `JSON` data `dictionary`. I trying to many times but cant extract particular value. I get only first  "business_category_name" but "business_details" under value "name" cant fetch. how it possible please help.

Thank you

## My JSON Data

```
{
 "status": [
{
  "business_category_name": "Banks\/Credit Unions\/Landers",
  "business_details": [
    {
      "img_url": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1464667619-pnc.jpg",
      "name": "PNC Bank",
      "des": "PNC offers a wide range of services for all our customers, from individuals and small businesses, to corporations and government entities",
      "address": "",
      "email": "andrea.kendall@pnc.com",
      "phone": "260-422-5922",
      "member_since": "2016-05-31",
      "img_company": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/member-logo\/1464667619-pnc.jpg",
      "website": "",
      "city": "Fort Wayne",
      "state": "IN",
      "zip": "46808"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "business_category_name": "Cleaning Services",
  "business_details": [
    {
      "img_url": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/uploads\/logo250.png",
      "name": "tsst company",
      "des": "rudurgg ",
      "address": "2005 s calhoun ",
      "email": "",
      "phone": "2602496687",
      "member_since": "2016-05-31",
      "img_company": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/uploads\/logo250.png",
      "website": "",
      "city": "fort wayne",
      "state": "in",
      "zip": "46825"
    }
  ]
}
 ]
 }
```

## MY code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"my url"]];
    response =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     NSError *error;
     NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
     NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
     NSLog(@"response data %@",json);
     NSArray *items = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
     pass = [items valueForKey:@"business_category_name"];
     NSLog(@"get category %@",pass);
}
```

Comment: for more easy, you can create a model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch only one dictionary from array try this

```
NSArray *statuses = [json objectForKey:@"status"];

for(NSDictionary *status in statuses){
   NSString *bussiness_category=[status valueForKey:@"business_category_name"];

   NSString *name=[[[status objectForKey:@"business_details"] firstObject] valueForKey:@"name"];

}
```

If you want to fetch all try this.

Create a mutable array and add all the name inside it and load into tableview like below

```
NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray new];

NSArray *statuses = [json objectForKey:@"status"];

for(NSDictionary *status in statuses){
   NSString *bussiness_category=[status valueForKey:@"business_category_name"];

   for(NSDictionary *details in [status objectForKey:@"business_details"]){
         NSString *name=[details valueForKey:@"name"];
         [names addObject:name];
   }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how to string name store in array and load in table view?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

```
NSArray *items = [json objectForKey:@"status"];

NSDictionary *firstObjOfItems = [items objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *business_category_name = [firstObjOfItems valueForKey:@"business_category_name"];

NSArray *business_details_Array = [firstObjOfItems objectForKey:@"business_details"];

NSDictionary *first_Object_of_business_details = [business_details_Array objectAtIndex:0]
;

NSString *name = [first_Object_of_business_details valueForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"name : %@",name);
```

You can fetch other parameters likewise. You should use for loop to go through every object. It is just example that how to reach at end element in your json data.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Fetch only one parameter i want to all name value fetch.

Comment: Yes that's why i have mentioned that use for loop to get every name of every object. I think you require two `for loops` one for `items` array and one for `business_details` array and then use `objectAtindex : i` or `j` instead of `0`

Comment: I required name array and name array load in UITableViewCell

Comment: Then make one mutable array and add name to that array from every iteration of your for loop and then use that name array as your data source of tableview

Answer (score 0):

here dataFromApi is string JSON format;

```
NSData *objectData = [dataFromApi dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id collection = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:0 error:&error];
```

after receiving collection you can find data using key value pair.

```
ex = string add = collection[@"name"];
```